# How do I obtain the rendered HTML from KnockoutJs (I have a good reason)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, components

Preface: I get it, 99% of the time one would *NOT* want to do this.  I also thought about explaining my reasons, but I'll leave you with "end user wants to see rendered components in the WYSIWYG editor, even if they can't be adjusted.  Figure it out."

With that in mind, does anyone know how to could get the rendered HTML from knockout representing a component?  I don't care if it is not two way bound, or if anything else breaks.  Just want the HTML.  Ideally I could just type `ko.renderComponent("component-name").toHTML()` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.  Just put whatever you want into temp. I used jquery to make creating a DOM element quick.

```
var temp = $("<your-component></your-component>");
ko.applyBindingsToNode(temp[0]);
var renderedHtml = temp.html();
```